# Can 助動詞(auxiliary verbs) be used with other 助動詞?

Tags: grammar, subsidiary-verbs

I've been learning about these for awhile, but everything I've seen them used in doesn't use more than 1 at a time. Is there a reason for that?

Also my materials don't really explain the subtleties behind using 込む(to do something in an upfront way, i.e.聞き込む) and 回る(to go around doing something, i.e. 歩き回る) as 助動詞. Is there anything more I should know?

Comment: I don't think those are [助動詞](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E_%28%E5%9B%BD%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95%29).

Comment: 「巻き込む」「歩き回る」などは「複合動詞」でしたっけ・・・？

Comment: I know couple of Russian books which elucidate compatibility of auxiliary verbs, but no English sources.

Comment: My source literature taught me the concept as an Auxiliary Verb, but that may be why I search turned up just north of jacksquat on the topic. The answer and the info that came from it will prove very valuable in my studies and extended research

Comment: @summea. They have, believe me. This topic has been on my mind ever since I came upon it, but have found precious little on. For example, nothing in my research thus far shown me what 上げる does to a verb, when used as a 複合動詞, as in 読み上げる. Are there any additional resources, web or written, you could point me to? Also, how do you change how a browser renders encoding? When I went to [this site](http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/26hukugoudousi.html), all I got was a spewing of random characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @snailboat and @Chocolate have noted, I think you are actually thinking about something called 複合動詞{ふくごうどうし} (or *compound verbs*.)

It is interesting to consider combining more than two verbs when creating 複合動詞{ふくごうどうし}... and it certainly is possible, according to the example word lists given in [this paper](http://doors.doshisha.ac.jp/webopac/bdyview.do?bodyid=BD00012642&elmid=Body&lfname=016000410007.pdf) by 林　翠芳 (LIN Cuifang).  LIN gives examples of times where 複合動詞{ふくごうどうし} can involve the process of combining three separate verbs into one compound verb (三次結合複合動詞{さんじけつごうふくごうどうし} vs 二次結合複合動詞{にじけつごうふくごうどうし}).

For example:

> 書{か}く＋立{た}てる＋すぎる　＝　書{か}き＋立{た}て＋すぎる　＝　書{か}き立{た}てすぎる
>
> 立{た}つ＋止{と}まる＋かける　＝　立{た}ち＋止{ど}まり＋かける　＝　立{た}ち止{ど}まりかける

**So in answer to the first question,** while there are times where three-verb-combined verbs exist, it's possible that the reason two-verb-combined verbs are more commonly seen is because the words have a simpler meaning or definition.  In other words, the more convoluted a word becomes, the more complex its meaning.

**In answer to the second question,** there has been [at least one similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-does-komu-%E3%83%BC%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80-at-the-end-of-a-word-mean) asked in regard to the meaning of ー込{こ}む when used at the end of a verb.  Though the meaning *may* at times go beyond what is listed in the current list of answers for [that other question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-does-komu-%E3%83%BC%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80-at-the-end-of-a-word-mean), I would still recommend reading that other question in order to get a better idea of any additional subtleties related to ー込{こ}む.

Finally, verbs ending with ー回{まわ}る are fairly straightforward *(typically being related to something "around" or "about", as you noted.)*

As far as 複合動詞{ふくごうどうし} go in general, I would recommend taking a look at [this paper](http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/26hukugoudousi.html) when time permits.  [The paper](http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/26hukugoudousi.html) better explains different functions, meanings, and aspects of 複合動詞{ふくごうどうし}.

Comment: I think the paper suggests that these "three-verb-combined verbs" are generally the combination of a *lexicalized compound verb* with another verb.  This second verb may be a simple verb or another compound verb (in which case they overlap).  In other words, it's usually (A + B) + C or A + (B + C), or in overlapping cases (A + [B) + C].

Comment: @snailboat Thanks; for the sake of this particular question, I am mostly trying to borrow a couple of examples from the paper to illustrate that there are times where triple verb compounds can occur. :)  I haven't heard of the term "lexicalized compound verb", before; thanks for the comment.

Comment: See [page 2](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/jcv.pdf) here for some discussion, starting with "The JCV [Japanese Compound Verb] is a highly productive form...".  In particular, "it is generally recognized that many more JCVs are in use than are lexicalized."

Comment: Is there any clear edge between such compound verbs and free chains of verbs in their "-masu stem" forms (which functions like adverb in the written language)?

Comment: @firtree Can you give an example of a "free chain" verb?

Comment: Not "chain verbs", but "verb chains". 手続き無事終わり, お目にかかり相談しました. Do I get somethig wrong?

Comment: @firtree Just for my clarification, what are you wanting this example sentence to say in English?  At the moment, I don't see a place in that sentence where there are two verbs being combined... :)  *(I do see places where there is a noun+verb being combined... and where there are some dropped particles... but I do not see a place where two or more verbs are being combined.)*

Comment: This is not an example sentence, this is two separate examples. Sorry.

Comment: @firtree Even if these are two different examples, I still do not see where there would be two verbs being combined, here :)  手続きが無事に終わりました。 and 〜お目にかかり、相談しました。  Whatever compounds there are here are actually being broken up by particles or punctuation... as far as I can tell. ^^;

Comment: There might be no particles or punctuation (especially in speech, no punctuation - though pauses and stresses come into action). Anyway, thanks. Seems my question was a bit too theoretical.

Comment: @firtree No problem; and sorry if my answers came off too "teacher-like"; I'm only a student, myself.  I think I know what you were getting at by dropping the particles in those examples... but technically-speaking, if we look at what particles might go between those words and verbs... I think the examples then become different than the original 複合動詞{ふくごうどうし} question... :)

Comment: Particles are for nouns, and where verbal forms can function both like nouns and like adverbs. The second use is similar to the usual Vて form, though it differs in where it is used - in the written text. I know about that far. And even after-noun particles can be omitted sometimes. So, structurally there seems to be no clear border between compound words and phrases. When particles are present it is definitely a phrase, but when it does not, the distinction weakens. Spaces cannot be guide and the only clue is frequency of use.